# How do I get props from a onChange() event?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I passed an `onChange` function into a react component along with another prop. In the `onChange` function I need to get the prop I passed into the component. How might I do that? I am thinking of using event.target but I don't know if props are returned from event.target.

Background:
I am trying to make a basic ideaboard and right now just want to create several inputtable textboxes based on an array in a file. The component `Idea` represents a single idea, and it has two text input areas.

```
function Idea(props){
    return(
        <div>
            <p>Date: {props.date}</p>
            <input 
                type = "text"
                value = {props.title}
                name = "title"
                placeholder = "title"
                onChange = {props.handleChange}
                />

            <textarea
                type = "text"
                value = {props.content}
                name = "content"
                placeholder = "content"
                onChange = {props.handleChange}
                />
        </div>)}
```

A parent component `Ideas` stores as an array of objects in state the content of the textboxes. Each element in the array is an object representing the data of one `Idea` component, and stores date, title and content.

```
import ideasData from "./ideasData
class Ideas extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            ideas : ideasData
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
```

A function in `Ideas`, `handleChange` is passed down as a prop to every `Idea` component rendered. It updates the array stored in `Ideas`'s state. For example, if I typed "things" into a "title" textbox of the third idea, then `ideas[2].title` should become "things". However, this requires me to retrieve the "index" prop from the component as otherwise it wouldn't know which element of the array in state should be updated. "index" is a prop passed down into every `Idea` component.

```
    handleChange(event) {
        const {name,value} = event.target
        let index = ????????
        let curIdeas = this.state.ideas
        curIdeas[index][name] = value
        this.setState(curIdeas)
    }
```

Comment: `this.props` i think is what you need?

Comment: you also have 2 `handleChange`?

Comment: @DanielA.White   handleChange is part of the parent component Ideas and performs setState on Ideas and is binded to Ideas. So I don't think this.props would work. I think I might be able to get it from event.target? I will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering the `Idea`s you need to pass the index as a prop.

```
this.state.ideas.map((idea, i) = > <Idea {...idea} index={i} />
```

Then inside `Idea` you call `handleChange` with the `index` coming from props.

```
onChange = {(e) => props.handleChange(e, this.props.index}
```

And get the `index` in the `handleChange`

```
handleChange(event, index) {
    const {name,value} = event.target
    let index = index
    let curIdeas = this.state.ideas
    curIdeas[index][name] = value
    this.setState(curIdeas)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! So I can just add additional parameters after the event in an onChange, onClick etc.?

Comment: @LahelLight if you pass a anonymous function, yes. But don't do `onChange={props.handleChange(e, index)}` this will cause a big problem